# ScrolledText doesn't scroll textbox all the way down. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

so I've got this python application that has an UI made with Tkinter.
I'm trying to add a scrollable textbox in the UI with the following command:
`text = tkscrolled.ScrolledText(app, width=46, height=20, bg="#e1e2e1", fg="black", highlightthickness = 0, padx=5, wrap=WORD, font=("Arial", 9))`

The problem is that the scrollbar is not sized based on the length of the textbox (if I scroll the bar all the way down, I'm only at half of the content in textbox but the scrollbar is reasizing if I scroll using scrollwheel on the mouse)

I searched all over the internet and most of the solutions points to use other things from Tkinter. The problem is that I'm not a professional and the UI is build using grid system, **and I cannot use another library that add a separated column for the scrollbar.** So is there a way to make it works with this code?

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog

def closeapp():
    app.destroy()

def main_UI(content)
    app = Tk()
    app.geometry("400x400")
    title = Text(app, width=52, height=3, bg="black", fg="white", spacing1=1, spacing3=1, highlightthickness = 0, wrap=WORD, font=("Arial", 9, "bold"))
    title.grid(row=0)
    title.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
    title.insert(INSERT, "\nTitle")


    text = tkscrolled.ScrolledText(app, width=50, height=20, padx=5, wrap=WORD, font=("Arial", 9))
    text.grid(row=1)
    text.insert(INSERT, content)
    Button(app, text='Accept', command=accept,bg="#ec6300", fg="white", width=40, font=("Arial", 9, "bold",)).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4)
    Button(app, text='Cancel', command=close,bg="#ec6300", fg="white", width=40, font=("Arial", 9, "bold")).grid(row=3, column=0, pady=4)
    app.resizable(False, False)
    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closeapp)
    app.mainloop()
    return 1
```

This is how it looks like when I run it:
[image]

This is how it looks like when I use the scrollbar all the way down:
[image]

But there is more text and I can not reach it using scrollbar. Scrolling using scroll wheel of the mouse will resize the scrollbar and let me go to the end of the file:
[image]

**The yellow squares are because I cannot share the content, I've left only one row to prove that there is different content for all cases**

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. I can't reproduce your problem, and it's highly unlikely that the scrolledtext isn't behaving properly. The problem is likely in your code. It sounds like the scrolled text is just not being told to fill the window.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Okay, I've updated it. I was thinking that something's wrong in that line, and because I cannot share the content I posted only the line that I thought it has a problem

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The code you posted won't work, but after fixing the issues I'm able to scroll around to see all of the text. Please make sure your example is _complete_ and accurately reproduces the problem.

Comment: You could actually provide a complete sample with the text just replace it all with "lorem ipsum" or sth.

Comment: If the length of each line is a bit long, the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Try calling `app.call(text._w, "sync")` after `text.insert(INSERT, content)`.

Comment: @acw1668 so in a way it worked, no it's opossite, the scrollbar will reach the end of text even if I don't scroll it all the way down. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the fact that the tool used `.grid()`

I removed all `grid()` functions and used `pack()` on all objects. The scrollbar is working fine now.